# How to implement the theory of copy movement in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, linguistics

Using this input:

`parse(Parse, [what,did,thomas,eat], [])`

I want to produce this output:

```
sbarq(
whnp(
    wp(what)
    ),
sq(
    vbd(did),
    np(nnp(thomas)),
    vp(
        vb(eat),
        whnp(
            wp(what)
            )
      ) % this is not in the input, I need to copy the entire whnp here
)
```

with this code:

```
parse(Tree) --> sbarq(Tree).

% rules
sbarq(sbarq(WHNP, SQ)) --> whnp(WHNP), sq(SQ).
whnp(whnp(WP)) --> wp(WP).
sq(sq(VBD, NP, VP)) --> vbd(VBD), np(NP), vp(VP).
np(np(NNP)) --> nnp(NNP).
vp(vp(VB)) --> vb(VB).

% lexicon
wp(wp(what)) --> [what].
vbd(vbd(did)) --> [did].
nnp(nnp(thomas)) --> [thomas].
vb(vb(eat)) --> [eat].
```

how can I change my code to copy the whnp into the vp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `WHNP` to the desired location as shown below:

[image]

```
% rules
 
sbarq(sbarq(WHNP, SQ)) --> whnp(WHNP), sq(WHNP, SQ).
whnp(whnp(WP)) --> wp(WP).
sq(WHNP, sq(VBD, NP, VP)) --> vbd(VBD), np(NP), vp(WHNP, VP).
np(np(NNP)) --> nnp(NNP).
vp(WHNP, vp(VB, WHNP)) --> vb(VB).

% lexicon
 
wp(wp(what)) --> [what].
vbd(vbd(did)) --> [did].
nnp(nnp(thomas)) --> [thomas].
vb(vb(eat)) --> [eat].
```

Example:

```
?- phrase(sbarq(T), [what,did,thomas,eat]).
T = sbarq(whnp(wp(what)), sq(vbd(did), np(nnp(thomas)), vp(vb(eat), whnp(wp(what))))).
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)